# How to customize the border-size of Button component in NativeBase?

Tags: react-native, native-base

I have been using NativeBase for my React Native project.

I can use inline styling to increase the border size of the `<Button />` component. Is there any way to style all the buttons used from NativeBase?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at this file https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/blob/master/Components/Widgets/Button.js

The style of the TouchableHighlight component is set using the method `prepareRootProps`

Which has `borderWidth: (this.props.bordered) ? 1 : 0,`

So if you did `<Button bordered=true />`. It will set the borderWidth to 1. However it doesn't seem like it allows to define your own width.